# PHP em conjunto a Mysql em registro de usuario

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de registro de usuário e ele vem apresentando alguns erros se alguém puder me ajudar com eles ficaria muito grato.

```
<?php 

include("conexao.php"); 

$Email = $_POST['Email'];

$sql_code ="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Email = '$Email'";

$confirma = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die($mysqli->error);

$veri = mysql_num_rows($sql_code);


if (isset($_POST['botao'])){

if (isset($_SESSION)) 
    session_start();

foreach ($_POST as $chave => $valor) 
    $_SESSION[$chave] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($valor);


if (strlen($_SESSION['Nome']) == 0) 
    $erro[] = "Nome em branco.";

if (strlen($_SESSION['Sobrenome']) == 0) 
    $erro[] = "Sobrenome em branco.";

if (substr_count($_SESSION['Email'], '@') != 1 || substr_count($_SESSION['Email'], '.')< 1 ) 
    $erro[] = "Email invalido.";



if (strcmp($_SESSION['Senha'], $_SESSION['Confse'])) 
    $erro[] = "As senhas precisam ser iguais";


if ($veri > 0 ) 
    $erro[] = "Email já cadastrado.";


if (count($erro) == 0) {

$code = "INSERT INTO `usuario` (
`Id_Usuario`, 
`Nome_Usuario`,  
`Sobrenome_Usuario`, 
`Email`, 
`Senha`, 
`Idade`, 
`Sexo`)
VALUES (
NULL, 
'$_SESSION[Nome], 
'$_SESSION[Sobrenome]', 
'$_SESSION[Email]', 
'$_SESSION[Senha]', 
'$_SESSION[idade]', 
'$_SESSION[Sexo]')";

$con = $mysqli->query($code) or die($mysqli->error);}} if (count($erro) > 0 
) {
foreach ($erro as $valor) {
        echo "$valor <script>location('login.php')</script>";
}}?>
```

Segue a imagem de erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro `mysql_num_rows` é porque você está usando mysqli. Então o código correto é `mysqli_num_rows`. Além disso, para você contar a quantidade de registro você precisa usar a variável da `query` assim:

```
$veri = mysqli_num_rows($confirma);
```

O erro da variável `$erro` é que ela não foi definida antes. Você pode fazer isso:

```
 $erro = array(); // aqui eu defini a variável em array
if (strlen($_SESSION['Nome']) == 0) 
    $erro[] = "Nome em branco.";

if (strlen($_SESSION['Sobrenome']) == 0) 
    $erro[] = "Sobrenome em branco.";

if (substr_count($_SESSION['Email'], '@') != 1 || substr_count($_SESSION['Email'], '.')< 1 ) 
    $erro[] = "Email invalido.";

 ... resto do código ...
```

O erro para inserir no banco está na string, está faltando um ('):

```
'$_SESSION[Nome], // <- bem aqui
'$_SESSION[Sobrenome]', 
'$_SESSION[Email]', 
'$_SESSION[Senha]', 
'$_SESSION[idade]', 
'$_SESSION[Sexo]')";
```

O certo é:

```
'$_SESSION[Nome]', // <- bem aqui
'$_SESSION[Sobrenome]', 
'$_SESSION[Email]', 
'$_SESSION[Senha]', 
'$_SESSION[idade]', 
'$_SESSION[Sexo]')";
```

Se o erro persistir em algum lugar comente aqui.

*Observação: Se a Idade for um inteiro esse registro `'$_SESSION[idade]'` tem que ser alterado para `$_SESSION[idade]`. Sem aspas.*

Comment: Deu tudo certo obrigado